# Tan/Brown graphic novel about family in a beach and kid with frog/toad head

Tags: identification-request, comics

I'm trying to find a comic/graphic novel I once saw, but do not remember its name nor author.

Here are some things are remember (or think I remember):

- It was monochromatic, but instead of the normal black, used a light brown/tan as primary color.
- Probably took place on a beach.
- Was about a troubled family.
- The family had three kids (two boys and one girl, I think)
- The youngest kid was somewhat awkward and this was represented by him having a frog/toad head. I'm also pretty positive this kid's name was Peter.

Comment: Welcome to Literature Stack Exchange! Could you please add in which language you read it (especially if that was the book's original language) and either when it was probably published (roughly) or (failing that) when you read it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got the answer from another website: the book is [*Bottomless Belly Button*](http://dashshaw.com/bottomless.html) (author's site) and the author is Dash Shaw.

It's about three brothers who reunite in a house at the beach after they hear their parents are divorcing. It focuses on the complicated relationships between all of them.It was published in 2008.

This is the cover:

[image]

And this is an example of a page inside:

[image]